# How to populate an array in javascript using data sent through Model List

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a list in my model, EmployeeList

In my View I want to to populate an array from EmployeeList(from Model) and use it as autocomplete for tags.  It seems that the array isn`t being poplulated from the List nor is the autocomplete working.  Help please.

The code in the View is as follows:

```
 <title>jQuery Autocomplete example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<!-- Listing 14.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var employeeList = '@Model.EmployeeLis.toArray();'


        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: employeeList

        });
    });
</script>
```

```
 <h1>Type your name here</h1>
<%= Html.TextBox("tags") %>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class which will generate a JSON representation of you model array:

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
<title>jQuery Autocomplete example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")"></script>
<!-- Listing 14.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var employeeList = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.EmployeeList));
        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: employeeList
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also note the way I have used the `Url.Content` helper in the script inclusions to avoid hardcoding urls which might not work when your application is deployed.